# Wrapp existing library (.so) in jni for android app

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I wanna realize this [idea](http://www.skyscanner.net/sites/default/files/images/news/mobile_sdk_diagram_cpp_landscape_android.png). I spent several days searching for information, but could not find anything. All tutorials say how to write my own library with JNI, but how to wrap already existing? I need just simple tutorial step by step (and why? if it possible). So I wanna start create native android application.

---

What I have : 
I create C++ library in QTCreator by tutorial from [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZewJ4iHQvXY): simple library on C++ (.so) with headers (.h) which do simple cout in console:
Not compiled code **mylib.cpp**:

```
#include "mylib.h"     

MyLib::MyLib() { }

void MyLib::Test() {
    qDebug() << "Hello from our DLL";
    // .so 
}
```

Header **mylib.h**:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#include "mylib_global.h"
#include <QDebug>

class MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT MyLib
{

public:
    MyLib();

    void Test();
};

#endif // MYLIB_H
```

and **mylib_global.h** (I think it does't matter)

So after **build** I have **myLib.so**.

And now I need wrap it in my android app. So I don't understand what I need to do for it.
I'm develop in **Android Studio**. And what I know:

Create in java package LibWrappClass with native method - something like "simplePrint()":

```
public native void simplePrint();
```

I need to create in /src/main folder "jni". Create **Android.mk**, **myLibWrapper.h** and **myLibWrapper.cpp**. But I don't understand what I need to write in Android.mk for connect my **myLib.so** to "myLibWrapper.h", and **where should I put** my library with headers. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

After adding the native method in your java code, You simply build the project. Now you need to move to the location where the class files are written by your IDE. Since you use Android Studio, it must be somewhere your project folder with path

```
out/production/YourModuleName
```

Open the location in commandline and run the `javah` command to generate the header file for your native function

```
javah -d <your jni folder path> <com.YourPackage.YourClass>
```

The class `YourClass` should be where you have declared the native method. This command will create a header file with name something like `com_YourPackage_YourClass.h` with a function declaration looks like

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_YourPackage_YourClass_simplePrint
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

Implement this function in a C/C++ file with whatever operations you have to perform on jni side.

Then, Define the Android.mk file, In this case it will be something like

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If you have multiple source files add them in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` separated by space.

Next, go to your jni folder and build the project using command `ndk-build`. This will place the .so file inside the android folder `libs/armeabi`

Finally rebuild the Android project from Android studio and run.

For detailed instructions and complete source checkout this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gnuanu/252fd406f48f7da2c1c7)

Comment: Do you read the question? And where I need use my already existing **myLib.so**? You write how create library and I question how to use already existing.

Comment: I read your question and the answer is simple, if the existing so file is built with the code you given above, you cannot link it from your java code. And I presume that you have built it with GCC not NDK. In order to make it work on an Android device you must build it with a NDK toolchain.

Comment: Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gnuanu/252fd406f48f7da2c1c7) for more details and code.